# how to prevent click from propagating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following div and click listeners:

```
  $('.right-col .modal-container').live('click',function(e) {
       $(this).remove();
       $('.right-col .modal-backdrop').remove();
  });


<div class="modal-container">
    ....some other buttons and html elements inside
</div>
```

The issue is that when ever I click on a button inside this modal-container element, it would also trigger the click function at .modal-container. How do I avoid this cascading?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=prevent+click+from+propagating&oq=prevent+click+from+propagating&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60.554j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: live is deprecated and removed from up 1.9+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I make sure that this click event doesn't come from a
>   propagated click, but a direct click on this div

Use `if (this == e.target){`

```
$('.right-col .modal-container').on('click',function(e) {
    if (this == e.target){
       $(this).remove();
       $('.right-col .modal-backdrop').remove();
    }
});
```

`e.target` is the element that ***you clicked directly*** as opposed to `e.currentTarget` which is the current element in the propagation. This will work also in case of ***event capturing*** because with event capturing: the event is fired on the container first before reaching the clicked element.

For performance benefit, you should also try `stopPropagation` as suggested by @Karl-André Gagnon to stop event propagation in case of ***event bubbling***

[Difference between event capturing and event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Answer (score 0):

After writing your question title in google, here the first link : http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

And here how to use it :

```
$('.right-col .modal-container').on('click',function(e) {
    $(this).remove();
    $('.right-col .modal-backdrop').remove();
}).find('button').click(function(e){ //guessing you have a <button> in the div
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: what if the question was the other way around, how do I make sure that this click event doesn't come from a propagated click, but a direct click on this div

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `div.modal-container` to be the target, you can register the click event on the `<button>` instead. Assuming you'd have a class name for the button as `.modal-container`, you can try this:

```
$("button.modal-container").live('click', function(e){
    // your button specific actions here
    // ...

    $(e.target).parents(".modal-container").first().remove();
});
```